# Hard To Trace Memory Leak

Tags: c++, memory-leaks, c++14, valgrind

I am new to c++ programming, and am having a lot of difficulty tracing down a memory leak, Can you help me find where this is happening?
This is what valgrind says:

```
> ==9851== Memcheck, a memory error detector
==9851== Copyright (C) 2002-2015, and GNU GPL'd, by Julian Seward et al.
==9851== Using Valgrind-3.11.0 and LibVEX; rerun with -h for copyright info
==9851== Command: ./lab6 in81.txt out.txt
==9851==
==9851==
==9851== HEAP SUMMARY:
==9851==     in use at exit: 72,760 bytes in 2 blocks
==9851==   total heap usage: 198 allocs, 196 frees, 130,465 bytes allocated
==9851== 
==9851== 56 bytes in 1 blocks are definitely lost in loss record 1 of 2
==9851==    at 0x4C2E0EF: operator new(unsigned long) (in /usr/lib/valgrind/vgpreload_memcheck-amd64-linux.so)
==9851==    by 0x4025EF: AVLTREE<std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> > >::insert(std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> >&, AVLTREE<std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> > >::node*&) (AVLtree.h:228)
==9851==    by 0x402666: AVLTREE<std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> > >::insert(std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> >&, AVLTREE<std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> > >::node*&) (AVLtree.h:234)
==9851==    by 0x4026AA: AVLTREE<std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> > >::insert(std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> >&, AVLTREE<std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> > >::node*&) (AVLtree.h:239)
==9851==    by 0x402666: AVLTREE<std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> > >::insert(std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> >&, AVLTREE<std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> > >::node*&) (AVLtree.h:234)
==9851==    by 0x401F74: AVLTREE<std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> > >::insert(std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> >&) (AVLtree.h:297)
==9851==    by 0x4016FE: interpretLine(std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> >, AVLTREE<std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> > >&, std::__cxx11::basic_stringstream<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> >&) (Main.cpp:20)
==9851==    by 0x401BF3: loadFile(char*, std::__cxx11::basic_stringstream<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> >&) (Main.cpp:68)
==9851==    by 0x401E6A: main (Main.cpp:91)
==9851== 
==9851== 72,704 bytes in 1 blocks are still reachable in loss record 2 of 2
==9851==    at 0x4C2DB8F: malloc (in /usr/lib/valgrind/vgpreload_memcheck-amd64-linux.so)
==9851==    by 0x4EC3EFF: ??? (in /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libstdc++.so.6.0.21)
==9851==    by 0x40104E9: call_init.part.0 (dl-init.c:72)
==9851==    by 0x40105FA: call_init (dl-init.c:30)
==9851==    by 0x40105FA: _dl_init (dl-init.c:120)
==9851==    by 0x4000CF9: ??? (in /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/ld-2.23.so)
==9851==    by 0x2: ???
==9851==    by 0xFFF000626: ???
==9851==    by 0xFFF00062D: ???
==9851==    by 0xFFF000636: ???
==9851== 
==9851== LEAK SUMMARY:
==9851==    definitely lost: 56 bytes in 1 blocks
==9851==    indirectly lost: 0 bytes in 0 blocks
==9851==      possibly lost: 0 bytes in 0 blocks
==9851==    still reachable: 72,704 bytes in 1 blocks
==9851==         suppressed: 0 bytes in 0 blocks
==9851== 
==9851== For counts of detected and suppressed errors, rerun with: -v
==9851== ERROR SUMMARY: 1 errors from 1 contexts (suppressed: 0 from 0)
```

This is my Insert Function:

```
int insert(someType& someData, node*& currentSpot)
{
    int i = 0; //i is nodes height.
    bool isRight = false;
    if (currentSpot == NULL)
    {
        currentSpot = new node(someData);
        size++;
        return 1;
    }
    if (someData < currentSpot->data)
    {
        i = insert(someData, currentSpot->kids[0]);
        isRight = false;
    }
    else if (someData > currentSpot->data)
    {
        i = insert(someData, currentSpot->kids[1]);
        isRight = true;
    }
    //rebalancing the tree;
    rebalance(currentSpot, isRight);
    //adjusting the height of the tree after rebalancing it.
    currentSpot->adjustHeight();
    return ++i;

}
```

This is what my remove function looks like:

```
bool remove(someType& d, node*& n)
{
    //not passing by reference, in order to use recursion as a stack
    if (n == nullptr) return false;
    bool found;
    if (d > n->data)
    {
        found = remove(d, n->kids[1]);
    }
    else if (d < n->data)
    {
        found = remove(d, n->kids[0]);
    }
    else if (d == n->data)
    {
        //use ctr
        // take min value from
        if (n->kids[1] != nullptr)
        {
            // case 1
            // 2
            //  \
            //   3
            //  ...
            someType minimumValue;
            minValue(n->kids[1], minimumValue);
            n->data = minimumValue;
            rebalance(n, n->tallerChild());
            n->adjustHeight();
        }
        else if (n->kids[0] != nullptr)
        {
            //case 2
            //   5
            //  /
            // 4
            // ......
            node* temp = n;
            n = n->kids[0];
            n->adjustHeight();
            size--;
            delete temp;
        }
        else
        {
            if (n == root) root = nullptr;
            node* temp = n;
            n = nullptr;
            size--;
            delete temp;
        }
        //found and eliminated, tree integrity has been preserved.
        return true;
    }
    //after recursively going down to n, going back up the stack adjusting the height
    rebalance(n, n->tallerChild());
    n->adjustHeight();
    return found;
}
```

These are my destructor & clear function:

```
void clear()
{
    if (root == nullptr) return;
    root->clear();
    delete root;
    root = nullptr;
    size = 0;
}
~AVLTREE()
{
        clear();
}
```

This is my nodes clear function:

```
void clear()
        { 
            if (kids[0] != nullptr)
            {
                kids[0]->clear();
                delete kids[0];
            }
            if (kids[1] != nullptr)
            {
                kids[1]->clear();
                delete kids[1];
            }
        }
```

Comment: `node*& currentSpot`? That doesn't seem to be a correct parameter.

Comment: 1. Use std::unique_ptr to indicate ownership (of nodes). 2. Get rid of any 'clear' functions and move that functionality to destructors. 3. Why not just use std::map, it's there and somebody else already debugged it for you.

Comment: Can you show the code of rebalance() ?

Comment: @DeepCoder It's a reference to a pointer.

Comment: What is the object definition for `node`? I'm moderately surprised it doesn't crash on the line saying `node* temp = n;
            n = nullptr;
            size--;
            delete temp;` itself.

Answer (score 0):

> ==9851==    at 0x4C2E0EF: operator new(unsigned long) (in /usr/lib/valgrind/vgpreload_memcheck-amd64-linux.so)
>
> ==9851==    by 0x4025EF: AVLTREE, std::allocator > >::insert(std::__cxx11::basic_string, std::allocator >&, AVLTREE, std::allocator > >::node*&) (AVLtree.h:228)

Here it's telling you that in AVLtree.h on line 228 you have a

```
new unsigned long;
```

You haven't annotated any of your code to be line 228 of AVLtree.h, and nothing in your code `new`s anything that's not a more complex type (e.g. `node`).

The second issue

> ==9851== 72,704 bytes in 1 blocks are still reachable in loss record 2 of 2
>
> ==9851==    at 0x4C2DB8F: malloc (in /usr/lib/valgrind/vgpreload_memcheck-amd64-linux.so)
>
> ==9851==    by 0x4EC3EFF: ??? (in /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libstdc++.so.6.0.21)
>
> ==9851==    by 0x40104E9: call_init.part.0 (dl-init.c:72)
>
> ==9851==    by 0x40105FA: call_init (dl-init.c:30)
>
> ==9851==    by 0x40105FA: _dl_init (dl-init.c:120)

`_dl_init` is the dynamic loader invoking constructors for static/global objects (https://github.com/lattera/glibc/blob/master/elf/dl-init.c#L121-L133).

So this indicates you have something at the static/global level leaking memory.